# I have a struct and its fields that I want to map them with constant values to avoid if checking. How to avoid that?

Tags: go, interface, polymorphism

I have a struct as follows:

```
type PromStatsServer struct {
    // To hold the total number of IGMP messages dropped by ACL check
    aclCounters *prometheus.CounterVec

    // To hold the total number of invalid IGMP messages
    invalidIGMPCounters *prometheus.CounterVec

    // To hold the number of successful JOIN request from IGMP clients
    successfulJoinCounters *prometheus.CounterVec

    // To hold the number of unsuccessful JOIN request from IGMP clients
    unsuccessfulJoinCounters *prometheus.CounterVec

    // To hold the number of JOIN request received from IGMP clients
    totalJoinCounters *prometheus.CounterVec
}
```

And, I have a const declaration as follows:

```
const (
    // Total Number of IGMP messages dropped by ACL check
    TotalNumIGMPMessagesDroppedByACLCheck = "DroppedIGMPMessagesByACL"
    // Total Number of invalid IGMP Messages
    TotalNumInvalidIGMPMessages = "NumInvalidIGMPMessages"
    // Total number of successful JOIN requests from IGMP clients.
    TotalNumSuccessfulJoinRequests = "NumSuccessfulJoinRequests"
    // Total number of unsuccessful JOIN request from IGMP clients.
    TotalNumUnsuccessfulJoinRequests = "NumUnsuccessfulJoinRequests"
    // Total number of JOINs received from IGMP clients
    TotalNumJoinsReceived = "NumJoinsReceived"
)
```

This is the function that I increment the values of those counter metrics.

```
// IncForPacket counts the number of times the couterName happens,
// Each call increments the associated counterName's value by 1.
func (ps *PromStatsServer) IncForPacket(vlan string, counterName PacketCounter) {
    switch counterName {
    case TotalNumIGMPMessagesDroppedByACLCheck:
        if ps.aclCounters != nil {
            ps.aclCounters.WithLabelValues(vlan, string(counterName)).Inc()
        }
    case TotalNumInvalidIGMPMessages:
        if ps.invalidIGMPCounters != nil {
            ps.invalidIGMPCounters.WithLabelValues(vlan, string(counterName)).Inc()
        }
    case TotalNumSuccessfulJoinRequests:
        if ps.successfulJoinCounters != nil {
            ps.successfulJoinCounters.WithLabelValues(vlan, string(counterName)).Inc()
        }
    case TotalNumUnsuccessfulJoinRequests:
        if ps.unsuccessfulJoinCounters != nil {
            ps.unsuccessfulJoinCounters.WithLabelValues(vlan, string(counterName)).Inc()
        }
    case TotalNumJoinsReceived:
        if ps.totalJoinCounters != nil {
            ps.totalJoinCounters.WithLabelValues(vlan, string(counterName)).Inc()
        }

    }
}
```

This is the interface.

```
IncForPacketCounter(vlan string, counterName string)
```

What kind of strategy would work for me so that I can erase those many `if`  checks inside `IncForPacket()`  implementation. Becasue it looks to me that those `if` checks are not considered as clean code. Does polymorphism work here with the help of interface? I'm calling it from another file and I don't think making those constants public is a good idea.

Any recommendation?

The code segments I've written seemed to me not clean enough. Hence, I'm looking for better strategies to make the code clean.

Comment: Methods can be invoked on `nil` non-interface values. Have the method `WithLabelValues` be implemented on a pointer receiver and do the `if receiver not nil` check inside the method. You'll just need to make sure that `Inc()` as well can handle an uninitialized receiver.

Comment: `WithLabelValues` belongs to Prometheus' package.